# Symfony entity constraints not respected on form used with ajax patch request

Tags: ajax, symfony, entity, assert, symfony-forms

On my symfony 6 project, I try to update a data with an Ajax request. First, I display an input tag with stimulus.js and then with an eventlistener I use the ajax request to handle and submit a form with the new value to check if it respect my entity asserts constraints. I try to update on property ('signature') from on Entity ('CompteClient').

My problem is that my constroller doesn't check asserts (not blank and length between 5 and 50) from my entity and always persist datas, even if it's not correct.
I already try to add constraint on my formBuilderType, but I always add the same result.
I used principally this page from documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html

Here's, part of my code :

-> in js, replace input by span tag while doing update :

```
afficherSpan(id, propriete){
        let aModifier = document.getElementById(propriete+'-'+id)
        let inputToDisplay = document.getElementById('input-'+propriete+'-'+id)
        let contenu = inputToDisplay.value
        this.enregistrer(id, propriete, contenu)
        //Span
        let spanToDisplay = document.createElement('span')
        spanToDisplay.setAttribute('id', 'span-'+propriete+'-'+id)
        spanToDisplay.innerText = contenu
        //Replace
        aModifier.replaceChild(spanToDisplay, inputToDisplay)
    }

    enregistrer(id, propriete, contenu){
        fetch("compte/"+id+"/modifier/"+propriete+"/"+contenu,
            {method: 'PATCH'}
        ) 
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .then(function() {
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

-> my formBuilder :

```
class SignatureType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('signature', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CompteClient::class,
            'validation_groups' => ['app_compte_client']
        ]);
    }
}
```

-> my property 'signature' from the CompteClient entity :

```
 #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 50)]
    #[Groups(["CompteClient:item:post", "CompteClient:signature:patch"])]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:'Veuillez renseigner une signature.', groups:["app_compte_client"])]
    #[Assert\Length(min:5, max:50, minMessage:'Veuillez renseigner une signature valide (> ou = à 5 car.).', maxMessage:'Veuillez renseigner une signature valide (< ou = à 50 car.).', groups:["app_compte_client"])]
    private $signature;
```

-> then my controller :

```
  #[Route('/compte/{id}/modifier/{propriete}/{contenu}', name: 'comptes_modifier', methods:['PATCH'])]
    public function modifier(CompteClientRepository $compteClientRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, int $id, string $propriete, string $contenu): Response
    {
      $compteClient = $compteClientRepository->find($id);
        try {
            if($compteClient){
                if($propriete == 'signature' && !empty($contenu)){
                    $form = $this->createForm(SignatureType::class, $compteClient);
                    if($request->isMethod("PATCH")){
                        $form->get('signature')->submit($contenu, false);
                        if($form->get('signature')->isSubmitted() && $form->get('signature')->isValid()){
                            $compteClient->setSignature($contenu);
                            $entityManager->persist($compteClient);
                            $entityManager->flush();
                            return new Response(
                                json_encode([   
                                'message'=> $propriete.' du compte de '.$compteClient->getNomCompte().' mis à jour avec succès'
                                ]),202
                            );
                        }else{
                          $errors = $form->getErrors(true, false);
                          return new Response(
                              json_encode([   
                                  'message'=> $errors
                              ]),406
                          );
                      };
                    } 
                }
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {    
            return new Response(
                json_encode([   
                $th
                ]),500);
        }
    }
```

So, even if I try to update signature with a string with length = 2, It's update in the db.
Someone have an idea ?

Comment: You need to set the `validation_groups` in your form to `['app_compte_client']` as that is the group you've specified in your `Assert`s. The `Groups` attribute (containing the value you're using now) is used for serialization.

Comment: Hi Marleen, thanks for your response ! 
You right, I make the change in my code and update my stackoverflow post with your recommandation ; but it doesn't fix the problem. I can again update data that doesn't match with my asserts